# masking password input in windows terminal in C

Tags: c

I am on Windows and have tried the following code to mask password input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    char ch, password[13];
    printf("\nEnter Password (Upto 12 chars.): ");
    while (i < 12) {
        ch = getch();
        if (ch == ' ') {
            --i;
        } else if (ch == '\b') {
            printf("\b \b");
            i -= 2;
        } else if (ch == '\r')
            break;
        else {
            password[i] = ch;
            printf("*");
        }
        ++i;
    }
    password[i] = '\0';
    printf("\nPassword: %s",password);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with above code is that when I have inputted no characters and I press backspace then the printed string `Enter Password (Upto 12 chars.):`  gets its characters erased one by one. This I was able to work around by doing this `Enter Password (Upto 12 chars.):\n` and now it won't delete its characters. But there is another problem and that is whenever I try to close the terminal by pressing `Alt+F4` the two keystrokes get considered input by getch() and I get two characters returned and displayed. I know it is my fault as the else part takes anything except `\r`,`\b` and white-space but I want help fixing it.

What I want is to be able to mask password input without any of the above problems. I have used MySQL Command-line client before and it asks for password input just fine. Anything like that or close to that would be appreciated.

I should mention this is for a University project.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you are using the non-echoing `getch()` why do you need to output backspaces? Anyway, if you are using console i/o then use `cprintf` instead of the `stdout` version `printf`.

Comment: As for `getch()` returning twice for function and cursor movement keys, make a little key input function. There are two 'escape' characters that are used. It is easy to find out which they are. If one of them is received, go get another `getch()` and process accoringly. You can convert such input to an `int` value > 256.

Comment: @WeatherVane I was able to find ASCII code of the `Esc` key (27) and was able to ignore it but I don't understand what to do next. Also, cprintf() doesn't work

Comment: Function and cursor keys give two values (`0` or `224`, and another value), so if you want to ignore those keys, when you get `0` or `224` call `getch()` again and continue. I don't think you should ignore the Esc key, it was pressed for a reason. Ctrl-C won't terminate a program in console input.

Comment: "`cprintf()` doesn't work". It *does* work, so what do you mean?

Comment: You forgot to `#include conio.h` please take note of compiler warnings.

Comment: I get the error `undefined reference to cprintf' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status` on windows with MinGW. I have also added `conio.h`

Comment: I'd say that conio.h is non-standard, obsolete and should never be used. Why do you recommend its use, @WeatherVane?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I didn't recommend it. I said it must be included, because OP is on Windows and it is needed for the `getch()` function which OP uses. It is non-standard, but not obsolete. Are you thinking of Borland Turbo C++?

Comment: I just want to mask password input without having any of the problems I've stated. If `getch()` does not work then maybe something else that is better would be fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my own code. Took some inspiration from some old C++ code (not copy pasta).

It ignores whitespace, `Esc` key, function and arrow keys, works properly on backspace, and breaks out of the loop on hitting `Tab` or `Enter`. And now it doesn't delete characters from `printf()` string when hitting backspace on empty input.

The trick is to only assign input when all other `if` and `else if` conditions are not met and increment the counter in that `else` block only. And then when the loop ends put a `'\0'` at the last index of the string.

Here is the code:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define PASSWORD_LENGTH 12
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    char password[PASSWORD_LENGTH + 1];
    int ch;
    printf("\nEnter Password (Upto 12 chars.): ");
    while (i < PASSWORD_LENGTH) {
        ch = getch();
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == 27) {
            continue;
        } else if (ch == '\b') {
            if (i > 0) {
                printf("\b \b");
                --i;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        } else if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\t') {
            break;
        } else if (ch == 0 || ch == 224) {
            ch = getch();
            continue;
        } else {
            password[i++] = ch;
            printf("*");
        }
    }
    password[i] = '\0';
    printf("\n,%s,", password); //this can be removed as it is only for displaying output
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, just curious - how long did you wait for an answer before you started debugging it yourself?

Comment: I was doing it myself while waiting for an answer. I kept refreshing the page to find any new answers or comments. While browsing for answers about C password masking, I found an old post on msdn forums which gave me some inspiration and I got working in that direction and here I am with the answer.